# Django all over sudden has refused to load static files

Tags: python, django

Django server was loading the static files successfully but all over sudden it has refused to load the files what might be the problem?
i am using Django 2.2.1 and Python 3.6
the following are some of the files that can be used to identify the problem
All my static files are in the static folder

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .forms import Vacancy,Personal,Academic,Other

from . import views

app_name='account'

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('register/', views.registerEduc, name='register'),
path('registerApp/', views.registerApp, name='register_applicant'),
path('signin/', views.user_login, name='signin'),
path('add_student/', views.add_student, name='add_student'),
path('view_student/', views.view_student, name='view_student'),
path('view_applicant/', views.view_applicant, name='view_applicant'),
path('edit_applicant/', views.edit_applicant, name='editApplicant'),
#path('delete_student/?p<student_id>[\w+]+', views.delete_student, name='delete_student'),
path('delete_student/<str:student_id>', views.delete_student, name='delete_student'),
path('search_student/', views.search, name='search_student'),
path('post_vacancy/', views.postVacancy, name='postVacancy'),
path('printDoc/', views.print_pdf, name='print_pdf'),
path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
path('dashboard/',views.home_educ,name='dashboard'),
path('dashboardTSC/',views.home_tsc,name='htsc'),
path('apply/',views.FormWizardView.as_view([Vacancy,Personal,Academic,Other]),name='apply'),
path('password_change/',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),name='paas.change'),
path('password_change/done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(),name='pass.change.done'),

]
```

Response

```
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:18] "GET /account/signin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20195
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:24] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1687
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:24] "GET /static/style5.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1654
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:24] "GET /static/all_files/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1786
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:24] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1675
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:24] "GET/static/all_files/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1768
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:24] "GET /static/all_files/css/fontastic.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1705
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:25] "GET /static/all_files/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1705
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:25] "GET /static/all_files/css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1696
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:25] "GET /static/all_files/css/style.default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1717
[22/Mar/2020 20:36:25] "GET /static/all_files/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1717
```

The problem seem to have arose when i added a weasyprint CSS  functionality function to my project however removing it doesnt solve the issue now, though i dont know if its the cause.

here is the function

```
def print_pdf(request):
 #applicant = get_list_or_404(Application)
 code=qr.make('TSC Recruitment List')
 code=code.get_image()
 applicant=Application.objects.all()
 html = render_to_string('pdf.report.html',
                        {'applicant': applicant,'code':code})


 response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=successful.pdf'
 css=weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT+'/css/pdf.css')
 weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,stylesheets=[css])
 return response
```

Comment: Please add the details: settings, paths, urls, response statuses.

Comment: I have already added the necessary codes... How can the community assist me